# iPhone UITableVIew reloaddata causes the app to crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am implementing a functionality similar to pagination with UITableView.
The view controller is inherited from UIViewController and has a table view bound from Nib with an Outlet. I maintain an array to store the current objects visible in the table view.On clicking next and previous button I removeAllObjects and then add new objects to be displayed , which is followed by [self.tableView reloadData]. The application seems to crash at this point.I use iOS 4.1 for the same.

While using iOS 3.1 the functionality seems to work.Can any body point the reason?

Comment: What is the error? What does the stack look like when it crashes? We'll need more information in order to be of any help.

Comment: 0x06d61dc0 in ??
0x0269bb6c in CFRelease
0x0277d959 in -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
0x0272d973 in -[NSMutableArray removeAllObjects]
0x003ce48d in -[UITableView reloadData]
0x0003b1a8 in -[FlightStatusResultsByRoute refreshDisplay:] at FlightStatusResultsByRoute.m:158
0x000d621a in __NSFireDelayedPerform
0x02765f73 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
0x027675b4 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
0x026c3dd9 in __CFRunLoopRun
0x026c3350 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
0x026c3271 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
0x02fdf00c in GSEventRunModal
0x02fdf0d1 in GSEventRun

Comment: You may try to set the array to nil after clean the array. Seem the table cell try to read the data from the array before reload.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to be related just with the timing of doing things (updating datasource, delegate and reload data)

Even if not ... this project already does what you want to do I believe:
https://github.com/honcheng/PanelTableView and you can find a video of what it does here:
http://www.honcheng.com/

I haven't tried but seems to work ;)

Comment: datasource and delegate are set to the UIViewCOntroller class in the NIB.i dont think we need to update that with my implementation

Comment: The problem is that he functionality work in ios 3.1 but not in 4.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something's getting over-released, or perhaps over-removed. I see a [NSMutableArray removeAllObjects] followed by a [NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex], which would be a real problem.

Comment: if it was the problem with memory management, it should'nt have worked with iOS 3.1 ,but on the contrary it works.

Comment: That's not the case, unfortunately. There have been a lot of changes to the OS, and subtle things can have a tremendous effect. Thread handling changes can significantly alter the order in which events happen, for instance, and what was a potential problem under an earlier OS but just didn't happen to appear can suddenly pop up under a new OS. WaiLam's comment about nilling out the array is a good one: my guess is that if you set it to nil after emptying it and before refilling it you'll find that the error stops (but the new tableview will likely be empty).